# open image with FLTK on windows

Tags: c++, jpeg, filepath, fltk

I'm having problem: I was trying to add image to my _fl_group_ but was not able to do so.

I was trying to identify where the problem occurs and according to specification on *fltk's* webpage, if image is opened with `fl_JPEG_image(const char* path)` constructor correctly, calling `im->w()` should `return > 0` but it does not.

I don't know if I'm entering path correctly (in proper way)? I'm on win and the path to file is `"e:\\zaloha\\Pictures\\my\\DSC_0242.jpg"` and that is the way I typed it but after opening width is still 0 here is my code:

```
Fl_JPEG_Image* im = new Fl_JPEG_Image("e:\\zaloha\\Pictures\\my\\DSC_0242.jpg");
double w = im->w();
double h = im->h();
double d = im->d();
images.push_back(im);
Fl_Box* box = new Fl_Box(10,10,600,400);
box->image(im);
Pic_GR->add(box);
```

so as a result I have no image draw.

Comment: Did you build the fltkjpeg.lib or did it come as a set of libraries?  If you have the fltk source, just single step into Fl_JPEG_Image and find out why it is not loading.  If you can't step into Fl_JPEG_Image, ensure that you're writing out the debug symbols to a suitably named pdb file (not vxxx.pdb which is the MS default)

Comment: the lib used is downloaded from fltk's page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution is simple:

Despite using *Windows* you have to enter *Unix* style path, so instead of backward `"\\"` simply use `"/"` so the path should look like this: `"e:/zaloha/Pictures/my/DSC_0242.jpg"`